# ASP.NET Core app not working after publish to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, webdeploy, kudu

I have an ASP.NET Core app which is running fine locally.

However, when I **publish** (Web Deploy) the site to Azure, I get a **403**: `You do not have permission to view this directory or page`.

I have a default controller and a route defined in **Startup.cs**:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

The folder structure after web deploy to Azure looks like:

```
|_ home
  |_ site
    |_ wwwroot (contains DLL's and files specified through 'publishOptions' in project.json)
      |_ wwwroot (the contents of the 'wwwroot' folder I have in Visual Studio)
      |_ Views (contains MVC views)
      |_ refs (contains referenced DLLs, I think?)
```

Any idea of what I should look for in project.json or the Kudu portal to figure out what's wrong?

My `project.json` file:

```
{
  "title": "My Web App",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "compile": {
      "exclude": [ "bin/**", "obj/**", "node_modules/" ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [ "wwwroot", "Views", "appsettings.json", "appsettings.*.json" ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "jspm install", "gulp build" ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://*:8000/"
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

For one, I was missing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration` NuGet package. When I added it, I also got a `web.config` file in the site root (which I included through `project.json`).

I also added `.UseIISIntegration()` to my `WebHostBuilder` in **Startup.cs**:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .UseIISIntegration() // This was missing
      .Build()
      .Run();
   }
```

I can now run it on **IIS Express** locally (although I guess it's IIS fronting Kestrel?), but when published to Azure I get error:
`HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure`

The event log in Azure states: `Failed to start process with commandline '"%LAUNCHER_PATH%" %LAUNCHER_ARGS%', ErrorCode = '0x80070002'.`

According to the documentation, the troubleshooting step is:

`If the server does not have Internet access while installing the server hosting bundle, this exception will ensue when the installer is prevented from obtaining the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) packages online. You may obtain an installer for the packages from the Microsoft Download Center.`

Not sure how this applies to **Azure**, though?

Comment: What version of dotnet are you using? Also, what packages do you have in project.json?

Comment: I've added my project.json file, running Core 1.0 RTM.

Comment: @TedNyberg Probably problem occurs from missing web.config in `publishOptions`. Try to add web.config like ` [ "wwwroot", "Views", "appsettings.json", "appsettings.*.json", "web.config" ]`.

Comment: I had that before, but there's no web.config in the project?

Comment: The web.config file appeared when I added the IIS integration NuGet package. :) You got me in the right direction, issue has been resolved! Thanks @ademcaglin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from insufficient IIS integration/configuration.

I had to add the following to `project.json`:

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  }
```

I also added a **postPublish** script for IIS publishing:

```
"scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

I also added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration NuGet package:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0"
}
```

This created a **web.config** file, which I had to modify as:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\My.Web.App.dll" arguments="" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally I added **UseIISIntegration** to my **WebHostBuilder**:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .UseIISIntegration() // This was missing
      .Build()
      .Run();
   }
```

A standard **Publish** (Web Deploy) from Visual Studio and the website started just fine on Azure (although in my case I also had to add a **prepublish** script for some Gulp tasks).

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem this morning, and have all these changes in my project.  Only difference is I'm deploying through VSTS.  Any insights?  Getting the same error message you were -  `403: You do not have permission to view this directory or page`.

Comment: For me the only change was to update the web.config to: `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>`

Comment: Could you post the folder structure on Azure once it's deployed? I am having the same issue and wonder if something is wrong with my nuget package.