# Unmodified ASP.NET Core app template won't run in Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, web-applications, asp.net-core

Here is what I've done

1. Open VS 2017
2. File new .net core web application (.NET Core)
3. F5 to run locally -> browser runs and app renders ok
4. Stop debug
5. Right click -> publish
6. Select new Azure web app
7. Publish succeeds
8. Browser does not open automatically. Click on url in output window. And see this ???

[image]

How to get to the app ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209335/asp-net-core-app-not-working-after-publish-to-azure) I fixed it. Solution was it install IISIntegration from nuget.

Had an aurelia app created via `dotnet new aurelia` that did the exact same thing. Same fix here too..